# XML string incorrectly output by TCPDF/barcode/Datamatrix

Tags: php, character-encoding, tcpdf, datamatrix

i'm converting this piece of XML string into a 2D barcode using TCPDF/Datamatrix. This is my string:

```
<AN14>G6Y0A3</AN14>
```

This is how i'm trying to generate the barcode:

```
$pdf->write2DBarcode('<AN14>G6Y0A3</AN14>', 'DATAMATRIX', 124, 189, 66, 66, $some_defined_style, 'N');
```

PDF is generated correctly, however when i scan it, i get:

```
[)>06<AN14>G6Y7O2<D;GS9>A03
```

If i insert a whitespace in the middle of **G6Y0A3** string resulting **G6Y 0A3**, i get a correct scan output.

I found out the issue is generated in this file: *tcpdf/include/barcodes/datamatrix.php*, specifically within this *getHighLevelEncoding()* function, however that's a way too low level programming for me.

Is this a bug? Am i doing something wrong? Maybe i'm missing to encode my xml string before sending it through *write2DBarcode()* function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a similar problem. After reporting to Git TCPDF, I was denied access there. They have a bug in the code for generating datamatrix.

Comment: Please use the comments section if you are not able to provide a real solution.

Comment: Hey Jaroslav, turned out their library does not handle very well some utf-8 strings. I had to dig into the library files and change some `ord()` functions by `mb_ord()` (i can't recall where exactly, though).